# Nested use of \ifcsname needs protection

Tags: conditionals, expansion, nesting

I have a macro `\command` to ensure that the names of macros in my documentation are consistently formatted. Been work great, until I had an urge to procrastinate and had this *brilliant* idea that I can easily catch most spelling errors of the macro names, by checking that the macro exists.

Seems simple enough. So I added:

```
\ifcsname#1\endcsname%
\else%
    \par\textbf{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash#1} is not defined.}
\fi%
```

to the macro that does the formating, where `#1` is the name of the macro. This seems to work fine in the basic case as illustrated by the MWE below that produces:

[image]

and correctly tells me that `bfseriess` and `\foo` are not defined.

However, if I attempt to use this in a nested fashion

```
\command{foo=\command{MyDef}}
```

I get the error message

> ```
> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> <to be read again> 
>               \protect 
> l.25 \command{foo=\command{MyDef}}
> ```

### Question:

I have a feeling that the solution is in the question listed in the references but I don't know exactly how to `\protect` things.  So, what changes can I make to the `\command` macro so that I can uncomment the last line in the MWE and the proper error messages.

### Reference:

- [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% The last line should not produce any error 
%% messages (red text) if these two are defined.
%
%\newcommand*{\foo}{}%
%\newcommand*{\MyDef}{}%

\newcommand{\command}[1]{%
    \textbf{\textbackslash#1}%
    %% Since this is used to typeset macro names, we
    %% can check for typos by ensuring the macro exists
    \ifcsname#1\endcsname%
    \else%
        \par\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbackslash#1} is not defined.}
    \fi%
}%


\begin{document}
To bold text use \command{textbf} or \command{bfseriess}.

A useful token is \command{foo}.

This token needs to be set with: 
%\command{foo=\command{MyDef}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not due to nested `\ifcsname`. For example, if you change the definition to `\newcommand\command[1]{(#1 is \ifcsname#1\endcsname \else not \fi defined)}` then the document compiles correctly.

Comment: @Aditya: Hmmm, you are indeed correct. So its just my fancy formatting that is getting the way somehow?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the LaTeX internals well to explain why that is happening.

Comment: @Aditya: Yeah, thought it was a simple matter of adding a few `\protects` here and there, but haven't guessed the correct sequence yet.

Comment: I think when it encounters the second backslash of `MyDef`, TeX thinks *the `\csname` should have ended by now!* and triggers that error so that needs to be hidden somehow. And what should be the error message by the way? Because that's not a valid token anyway.

Comment: @percusse: I think you are correct. This won't generate the correct result (as per my comment on Aditya's solution).  Was that what you were referring to?

Comment: The problem is the `\protect` that's hidden in the definition of `\textbf`. You can trigger the error message e.g. with `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{}\csname\foo\endcsname`

Comment: @cgnieder It's not only the `\protect` (one could get rid of it); but `\textbf` does *many* other unexpandable things that can't go inside `\csname...\endcsname`.

Comment: @egreg should I have said then: “the _first_ problem is ...“? I'm aware that all the `\text...` commands pose problems in expansion contexts but the details are not yet clear to me. Maybe I should ask a question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not at all sure what the intended behaviour is when the argument to `\command` isn't a command name, but this does something:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% The last line should not produce any error 
%% messages (red text) if these two are defined.
%
%\newcommand*{\foo}{}%
%\newcommand*{\MyDef}{}%

\protected\def\command#1{%
    \textbf{\textbackslash#1}%
    %% Since this is used to typeset macro names, we
    %% can check for typos by ensuring the macro exists
    \ifcsname\detokenize{#1}\endcsname%
    \else%
        \par\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbackslash#1} is not defined.}
    \fi%
}%


\begin{document}
To bold text use \command{textbf} or \command{bfseriess}.

A useful token is \command{foo}.

This token needs to be set with: 
\command{foo=\command{MyDef}}
\end{document}
```

---

Or updated as requested in comments to strip the argument before `=`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% The last line should not produce any error 
%% messages (red text) if these two are defined.
%
%\newcommand*{\foo}{}%
%\newcommand*{\MyDef}{}%

\protected\def\command#1{%
    \textbf{\textbackslash#1}%
    %% Since this is used to typeset macro names, we
    %% can check for typos by ensuring the macro exists
    \ifcsname\expandafter\beforeeq\detokenize{#1}=\beforeeq\endcsname%
    \else%
        \par\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbackslash\expandafter\beforeeq\detokenize{#1}=\beforeeq} is not defined.}
    \fi%
}%

\def\beforeeq#1=#2\beforeeq{#1}

\begin{document}
To bold text use \command{textbf} or \command{bfseriess}.

A useful token is \command{foo}.

This token needs to be set with: 
\command{foo=\command{MyDef}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the nested usage, I would like to be able to use something like `\StrBefore{\detokenize{#1}}{=}[\MacroName]` so that I could check for `\ifcsname\MacroName\endcsname` but can't quite figure how to get that to work in this case.

Comment: @PeterGrill so in this example you want to test for foo?  (This seems a very odd requirement:-) (Update on way....)

Comment: I agree that is strange, but I am only trying to make it work for the cases I need, not a general solution as this is for internal documentation purposes.  This does indeed work as I need but was hoping that it used `xstring` so that I could easily expand it if needed to handle other cases.

Answer (score 7):

By simply imitating the definition of `\doifundefined` from ConTeXt (defined in file `syst-gen.mkii`), adding `\detokenize` to the definition works.

```
\newcommand\command[1]
    {\textbf{\textbackslash#1}%
    %% Since this is used to typeset macro names, we
    %% can check for typos by ensuring the macro exists
     \ifcsname\detokenize{#1}\endcsname%
    \else%
        \par\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbackslash#1} is not defined.}
    \fi%
}%
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting... Indeed it does _appear_ to fix the situation, in that the code compiles. However, the macro is not yielding correct results.  If you un-comment the `\newcommand*{\foo}{}` and `\newcommand*{\MyDef}{}`, the only error message should be the one for `bfseriess`, but this is not the case. .... Oh, wait, I think that is what @percusse's comment is about...

Comment: When you uncomment the `\newcommand`s, the macro is checking if `\csname foo=\textbf{\textbackslash MyDef}\endcsname` is defined or not. Clearly, that montrosity is not defined.

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant about precusse's comment. I need to rethink how to handle the nested case properly.

Answer (score 6):

I would go for something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\mytypeset#1{%
\def\command##1{%
     \ifcsname##1\endcsname%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else%
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi%
}%
 \def\z{\detokenize{#1}}
 \command{\z}{\fbox{TRUE}}{\fbox{FALSE}}
}


\mytypeset{deff{f}f}

\mytypeset{def}

\mytypeset{foo=\command{MyDef}}
\end{document}
```

Note that when you are checking for a  "nested" command, as a matter of fact the code checks to see if:

```
  foo=\command{MyDef}
```

is a defined macro! With `csname`...`endcsname`, arbitrary commands of any characters ca be used. You can have a command `!$%.#!.o>,p\def}` for example. You can add the follow snippet
to the example that demonstrates the concept.

```
\expandafter\def\csname My$Def\endcsname{MyDef...}

\mytypeset{My$Def}

% prints MyDef...
\csname My$Def\endcsname
```

`\My$Def` now is a command and prints `MyDef..`, when executed.

Comment: Yeah, am trying to figure out how to handle the nested case since what I initially put together would fail miserably for that case.

Comment: @PeterGrill ...tricky stuff! :